# String or binary data would be truncated.?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building an input form in a C# web app. I can submit it just fine but I get the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated` error. I know its a length issue but Ive double checked everything but just cant seem to figure this out here.

```
{
    // Open Connection
    thisConnection.Open();

    // Create INSERT statement with named parameters
    nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO InventoryInput (Date, Item, Qty, WStatus) VALUES (@Date, @Qty, @Item, @WStatus)";


    // Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@QTY", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10);
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@WStatus", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);


    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Item"].Value = DropDownList1.Text;
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@QTY"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
    nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@WStatus"].Value = DropDownList3.Text;
    nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) Is ID auto incremented? (2) I believe that you have a typo. Notice `@Qty` and `@QTY`. AFAIK it's case sensitive.

Comment: Well, what are the lengths of `DropDownList1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` ? and `DropDownList3.Text`? The first (`TextBox1,Text`) is more interesting. Personally, I think you should be doing an explicit parse first, and giving it the DateTime, not the string

Comment: Likewise you shouldn't save a quantity as a string either - use an integer datatype

Comment: @Andre case-sensitivity depends on the db settings, and on master's db settings

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed, thanks Marc.

Comment: The reason Im doing Nchar is because when I had it as a float or decimal the system tossed me an error and I didnt know how to make a qty field a number without it going stupid. Does anyone know how to do that?  Ive tried nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Qty", System.Data.SqlDbType.numeric, 18);  but it didnt work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've mixed up two of your columns:

```
(Date,  Item, Qty,   WStatus) VALUES
(@Date, @Qty, @Item, @WStatus)
```

You're trying to insert your `@Qty` into the `Item` column (okay), and `@Item` into the `Qty` column (probably wrong).

I also agree with comments that some of the data types still look suspect - E.g. a non-numeric quantity.

Comment: Well spotted. The kind of bug that is so easy to overlook. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your inputs aren't too long with `Substring()`:

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Item"].Value = DropDownList1.Text.Substring(0, 255);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@QTY"].Value = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0, 10);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@WStatus"].Value = DropDownList3.Text.Substring(0, 50);
```

Comment: Putting them into a parameter of specified length will silently truncate them if they are too long anyway so this is not an explanation.

Comment: @DanielA.White Absolutely it might.  The error is because the data being sent to the `SqlCommand` exceeds the capacity of the column.  Ideally this would be a client-side validation check.

Comment: @DanielA.White: It seems sure that it will (at least here) given that the whole problems seems to be that one or more of them are too long. :)

Comment: Substring(0,X) throws and error if the string is smaller than X